# How to debug Async XUnit units tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, async-await, xunit

I've created some unit tests on asp.net core code, using XUnit.

I'm trying to call my service controller and check the result:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task TryGetData()
    {
        //Arrange
        WeatherController weatherController = new WeatherController();

        //Act
        ActionResult result = await weatherController.Get();

        //Assert
        JsonResult jsonResult = Assert.IsType<JsonResult>(result);
        List<Prediction> predictions = Assert.IsType<List<Prediction>>(jsonResult.Value);
        Assert.NotEmpty(predictions);
        foreach (Prediction prediction in predictions)
        {
            Assert.NotEqual(default(DateTime), prediction.Date);
            Assert.NotEqual(default(double), prediction.Temperature);
        }
    }
```

It work, it fails as expected on the Temperature being 0 for now.

But :

1. If I hit debug, the test fails but Visual Studio doesn't stop on it
2. If I put a breakpoint, nothing stops on it.

I use VS2019, Xunit 2.4.1, tried with the resharper test session and the one from Visual Studio, doesn't change anything.

Is that supported? I read somewhere this was not supported before XUnit 1.9, but I've the 2.4.1.

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: It is probably not failing where you think it is failing. Put a break point on the arrange and step down from there

Comment: @Nkosi I've a breakpoint on the first line

Comment: Any error messages in the Output window?

Comment: I finally found was happening, for some reason, my debug configuration of the project was not including debug symbol, not sure why, I just created it.